# beamer: finding out if there is content in the appendix

Tags: beamer, counters

I am trying to determine if there are pages in the appendix. If there are I want to show a separation page/frame as indicator but *in the handout mode only*. In my current setup (due to some peculiarities of the beamer modes) there is ALWAYS an `\appendix` command, so hooking into that would not work. However, when looking at the implementations of `\insertpresentationendpage` and `\insertappendixendpage` I am quite sure that I can determine it by looking at the value of `\beamer@startpageofappendix` but for some reason I am not able to even though I have used `\makeatletter`. I have tried with `\value`, prepending `\the` etc. to no avail... in the end I ended up with various error message, especially:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...pendix\@ empty \else \ifnum \beamer 
                                                 @startpageofappendix=\beam...
```

So my question is: how to avoid rendering a frame if there are frames after the `\appendix` command?

Comment: Can you try using \typeout to determine what \beamer@startpageofappendix really is or does?

Comment: Well, no, because that too gives me an `undefined control sequence` message. :) I'll try to create a MWE.

Comment: Lesson learned (again): try creating a MWE if you get stuck instead of staring at error messages for hours ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you try to access the counters within `\mode<handout>` (I have no idea why though). Just putting the mode switch within the if as below works fine.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
% To test this MWE set \test below and compile two times.
% test=1 shall render the first page only, test=0 will print 3 pages
\def\test{1}

\begin{frame}{}
    Main content\\
    Always shown.
\end{frame}


\makeatletter
\typeout{startpageofappendix=\beamer@startpageofappendix, endpageofdocument=\beamer@endpageofdocument}
\ifx\beamer@startpageofappendix\@empty
\else
    \ifnum\beamer@startpageofappendix=\beamer@endpageofdocument
        \mode<handout>{
            \begin{frame}{}
                Appendix follows...\\
                on pages \beamer@startpageofappendix{} to \beamer@endpageofdocument{}\\
                This frame should not be rendered w/o the last frame!
            \end{frame}
        }
    \fi
\fi
\makeatother

\appendix

\ifnum\test=0%
    \begin{frame}{}
        Appendix slide 1.\\
        If this is shown the previous frame should be shown as well.
    \end{frame}
\fi

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add this separation frame to the definition of the `\appendix` and check if `\inserttotalframenumber` is equal to `\insertmainframenumber`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>\appendix{%
    \ifnum\inserttotalframenumber=\insertmainframenumber
    \else
    \begin{frame}
        APPENDIX
    \end{frame}
    \fi
  \beamer@inappendixtrue%
  \only#1{\part{\appendixname}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@writefile{nav}%
    {\noexpand\headcommand{\noexpand\gdef\noexpand\insertmainframenumber{\the\c@framenumber}}}}%
  \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@appendixpages{\the\c@page}}}%
  \beamer@resetappendix}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```